# javafx textfield value to label in other view

Tags: user-interface, javafx, label, textfield

I got an asignment from school where i have to read in two names in one view, then we have to press a button that goes to another view and then the two names have to come in a label there. i have been trying to do this for some time but for some reason i can't figure it out.

Here is my code on the first view

```
    public class Startview extends GridPane {    
private TextField txtplayer1;
private TextField txtplayer2;
private Button play;
this.txtplayer1 = new TextField();
this.txtplayer2 = new TextField(); 
this.add(txtplayer1,2,1);
this.add(txtplayer2, 2, 2);
this.add(play, 2, 3);
public Button getplay() {
    return play;
}
```

this is the code on my presenter where i write the actions

```
private void eventHandlers() {
    view.getplay().setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            Gameview gameview = new Gameview();
            Gamepresenter presenter3 = new Gamepresenter(model, gameview);
            view.getScene().setRoot(gameview);
            gameview.getScene().getWindow().sizeToScene();
            gameview.getScene().getWindow().centerOnScreen();


        }
    });
```

and the gameview where the labels are on(which is also on a gridpane)

```
private Label name1;
private Label name2;
public Label getname1() {
    return Name1;
}

public Label getName2() {
    return Name2;

}
```

all help or tips are appreciated

Comment: Since you seem to be using a MVP design, do you have a model? You could just put the player names in the model...

Comment: In addition to what @James_D said, this assignments seems to aim at binding properties. There are a lot of tutorials out there, that will explain this to you. The official one can be found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/properties-binding-tutorial/binding.htm)

Comment: oh yeah right you have to use the setplayer and getplayer from your model. the only thing that isnt working for some reason is to get the value from txtplayer1. it isn't accepting the getter. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like @James_D said, just use the functions in your model. In your startview use the setName from your player-class and in gameview use the getName from your player class.